# How to take derivative of $F(u)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \int f^2(x) u_i^q(x) dx $

Tags: integration, derivatives, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

I have to find the derivative of a function. Could you help me to find it
$$F(u)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Omega} f^2(x)  u_i^q(x) dx $$

where $q \ge 1$, $f(x): \Omega \to R$, $u_i$ is membership function in which $u_i(x)=1$ for $x \in \Omega$, $0 \le u_i(x) \le 1, \sum_i u_i=1$

How to find:
$$\frac {\partial F(u)} {\partial u}=?$$

Note that we need to consider 2 cases: $q=1$ and $q>1$
As my solution that I found that if

$$\frac {\partial F(u)} {\partial u}=0$$
Then solution of $u$ is $$u= \frac {(f^2(x))^{\frac {1}{1-q}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} (f^2(x))^{\frac {1}{1-q}}}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$ the Fréchet derivative of the operator $F: u \mapsto F$(u) ?

Comment: Right. It is function of $u$

Comment: And is $u$ a function $u:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$? And is the integral over $\mathbb{R}$? If it's indefinite (= a primitive), the function $F$ is not well defined (sorry to ask about these precisions ;) )

Comment: $N$ is dimension, is it right? $f$ is just function of $x$. The integral is over $\Omega$, in which $f(x): \Omega \to R$. $0 \le u(x) \le 1$. $F$ is function of $F(x,u)$. I will updated my question to make more clear

Comment: There is some things that doesn't makes sense, you may want to correct it. First, $F$ doesn't depend on $x$, as it is a bound variable. Also, $u_i(x) = 1$ doesn't really makes sense in this context. And if you have $\sum_i u_i =1$, you have $F(u) = \int_{\Omega} f^2(x) dx$ for $q=1$ (just put the sum inside)

Comment: I edited it. Is it ok?

Comment: No, there lack a crucial piece of information : what is the space $u$ come from. We need to know how is defined $\|u\|$ to calculate the derivative of $F$. The derivative will be very different if $u \in (C(\Omega), \|.\|_{\infty})$ or $u \in (L^p(\Omega), \|.\|_{p})$ or another norm. In addition to that, I repeat, but your $F$ is constant if $q=1$ (so the derivative is always zero)

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. Please look at in that paper to see more clear https://www.dropbox.com/s/8a5jrttowohq1wf/Cmli.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I don't see where they use the Frechet derivative of $F(U,c,w)$ to compute the minimisation of $F(U,c,w)$...

Comment: Sorry. Let see the full version in page 4 eq. 16 in https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7isa68w3r19x0n/MICO.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Still no mention of the derivative of F. The method they used to obtain the minimum of F is not mentionned.

Comment: To find minimal, I think they used derivative because it is convex for each parameter. Hence, my goal is find derivative of above function

Comment: Notice that the above function is not the function on the paper, as f depend on i in the paper. And notice that the derivative is not necessary null at the minimum point, as it is an optimisation is under a constraint

Comment: To make more simple question, I just assume $f(x)=\| I(x)-...c_i\|^2$. Note that I just consider derivative of $u$, hence the assuming make sense. It is very similar fuzzy c mean techniques

Comment: But then the question you ask is different, $$\sum_{i=1}^N | I(x)- W(x)c_i|^2 u_i^p(x) \neq f(x) \sum_{i=1}^N u_i^p(x)$$

Comment: Sorry $f(x)=∥I(x)−...c_i ∥$